# Hide NSView overflow

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I'm a web dev guy. The `overflow:hidden` CSS property tells the render engine to not draw the current view's content across the parent's borders.

In my current project, I have a custom NSWindow with a custom `NSView` with rounded corners by using `NSMakeRect`, overwriting `drawRect:` and so on. A `WebView` inside the NSView is strechted across the entire `NSView` frame.

Now the `WebView 'overflows' the rounded corners of the`NSView`. What I do like to have is that the WebView has the same mask as the NSView.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also make sure your view sets clips subviews to true. As far as I understand you, this is what you are looking for, and prevents f.ex. images to reach out of the parent view.

```
[self.view setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a corner radius to the layer of a view.

```
myView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
```

You'll have to add `QuartzCore.framework`.